# Java JFrame not showing in ouput when InternalFrames are added

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, awt, jinternalframe

Guys! I have created a multipage image quiz in Java InternalFrames. I have instantiated the InternalFrame Class and added that to a JFrame. Although, I am not able to see any output. I am a rookie in Java and I am not able to find any resources to solve this issue. Below is the main function code.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {    
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();
        CSYTest obj = new CSYTest("Nainoor");
        obj.setVisible(true);
        desktop.add(obj);
        frame.setContentPane(desktop);
        obj.setVisible(true);
        obj.setSize(new Dimension(300, 200));               
    }
```

My program gets terminated as soon as it runs. Java SE - 1.7

Comment: Please show your logs

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB. 2) `JFrame frame = new JFrame();` Well `frame.setVisible(true);` should be a) the last thing, immediately after `pack()` is called, and more importantly.. b) **Included in the code!**

Comment: You are calling `obj.setVisible(true);` twice but never `frame.setVisible(true);` I guess the last two statements are supposed to use `frame` instead of `obj`.